# Open Workbook, transcribe data and close workbook... Workbooks.Open doesnt seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a simple task with VBA in Excel 2010 that is giving me many problems I was hoping the experts could help me with.  I am new to VBA and have no formal training, so it is likely I am just making a dumb mistake somewhere.  I am trying to open a workbook (Source.xlsx), and then take data from that workbook (Sheet1!A1:E1) and transcribe it into the current workbook (Target.xlsm) Sheet1!A5:A9.  I created Source and Target workbooks just so I could try and figure this out, but the actual "Target" workbook will be pulling data from multiple workbooks.  I intended on passing the filename to the function and using that filename instead of hard-coding in a name like "Source.xlsx".  This is the code I have so far:

```
    Public Function TranscribeFromClosedWb(SourcePath As String, SourceWb As String, SourceWs As String)
0       'Exits Function if an Error is thrown
1       On Error GoTo ErrHandler
2
3       'Stops Excel from updating the screen so that the Function runs faster and is more aesthetic to the User
4       'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
5
6       'Dimensionalizes the Arrays and counting variables to be used in the function
7       Dim SourceCell(1 To 5) As String
8       Dim cellData(1 To 5) As Variant
9       Dim TargetCell(1 To 5) As String
10      Dim i As Integer
11
12      'Establishes the cell references for each item in the Arrays.  5 shown here for example.  Arbitrary values in SourceCells and no values in TargetCells
13      SourceCell(1) = "A1"
14      SourceCell(2) = "B1"
15      SourceCell(3) = "C1"
16      SourceCell(4) = "D1"
17      SourceCell(5) = "E1"
18      cellData(1) = 42
19      cellData(2) = 42
20      cellData(3) = 42
21      cellData(4) = 42
22      cellData(5) = 42
23      TargetCell(1) = "A5"
24      TargetCell(1) = "A6"
25      TargetCell(1) = "A7"
26      TargetCell(1) = "A8"
27      TargetCell(1) = "A9"
28
29      'Dimensionalizes an Excel Object as a Workbook to hold the Source Workbook open while data gathering and function codes are proceeding
30      Dim SourceWbObject As Workbooks
31
32      'Simply checks to ensure Source file actually exists, and exits if it does not
33      If Dir(SourcePath & SourceWb) = "" Then
34          MsgBox ("File " & Chr(34) & SourcePath & SourceWb & Chr(34) & " was not found.")
35          Exit Function
36      End If
37
38      'Dimensionalizes a string variable to hold the complete filepath, and sets the Excel Workbook Object to the Source Workbook
39      Dim SourceWbPath As String
40      SourceWbPath = SourcePath & SourceWb
41      MsgBox ShiftPressed()
42      
43      Set SourceWbObject = Workbooks.Open(SourceWbPath, True, True)
44      'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
45      'SourceWbObject
46      MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & Chr(13) & Workbooks.Count
47
48      'Sets up a For loop that is supposed to cycle through the cells in the SourceCell Array and set the values gathered to items in the cellData Array
49      i = 1
50      For i = 1 To 5
51          cellData(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(SourceCell(i)).Value
52          'cellData(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(SourceCell(i)).Value
53          i = i + 1
54      Next
55
56
57      'Sets up a For loop that transcribes the values gathered in the above For loop to the items in the TargetCell Array
58      i = 1
59      Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Activate
60      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
61          For i = 1 To 5
62              ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Activate
63              ActiveCell.Value = cellData(i)
64              i = i + 1
65          Next
66      End With
67
68      'Basic Housekeeping: Closes the Source Workbook, and clears the Excel Object that held it.
69      'SourceWbObject.Close False
70      'Set SourceWbObject = Nothing
71
72
73      'Error Handling stub: Simply restores EnableEvents properties (which may have been disabled by the Error), and restores screen updating prior to exiting function
74 ErrHandler:
75      Dim Msg As String
76      Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
77      MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
78      Application.EnableEvents = True
79      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

I have tried many different iterations of Workbooks.Open, but nothing seems to work.  When I started this I didn't know how to get the Error info in a MsgBox, so I was using MsxBox to give me info that I could use to try and figure out what was going on.  The MsgBox after Line 43 is supposed to tell me that Excel has the correct workbook as the active workbook (it doesn't) and that it succeeded in opening the Source workbook as indicated by .Count going from 1 to 2 (it doesn't do that either).  I also ticked out different stuff as I was trying things to minimize the number of errors I caught, what is ticked out now is just the last iteration I tried before seeking help here.  I also ticked out ScreenUpdating and all that so I could visually see what it was doing, obviously I would restore that once I have code that works...  I receive multiple different errors depending on what I try, most common is Error 91: Object variable or With Block variable not set, but I don't understand this as the code stops before the With blocks and I have a Set statement on Line 43.  I have also gotten 429: ActiveX component cant create object at the same lines.  A thread on here stated that this could be a bug caused by Excel thinking the Shift key was depressed, so I copied some code that would return true if either shift key was depressed and displayed a MsgBox just before the Open line and it always returns False, so I don't think this is an issue.  Multiple sources, Excel tips, Mr. Excel, MSDN, and here all state that Workbooks.Open should do exactly what I want it to, but I cant figure out why it wont work for me... Sorry for the length, please help!  Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: `ThisWorkBook` always applies to one including the code so you should use `SourceWbObject` instead

Comment: Changing This Workbook to SourceWbObject in Lines 46 and 51 instead throws a compile error, Error 461 Method or Data Member Not Found.  I had tried this previously with no luck, forgot to mention that I had tried that...  I used ThisWorkbook in Lines 60 though 66 because I wanted that to affect the Target workbook, but my errors are occurring before the code even gets there...

Comment: try `msgbox SourceWbObject.path` what will it show?

Comment: .path is not an available method or property it seems... The only available options I have are Add, Application, CanCheckOut, CheckOut, Close, Count, Creator, Item, Open, OpenDatabase, OpenText, OpenXML, and Parent.  Anytime SourceWbObject shows up afterwards it throws a 461 Error, even in MsgBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SourceWbObject` should be declared as `WorkBook` not `WorkBooks`.
Then replacing `ThisWorkBook` with `SourceWbObject` should do this.

Comment: You were correct! Sorry for the long delay in confirming that for you, it has been a busy few months and I forgot that I hadnt come back and told you so... Thank you very much, this has taught me at the least to go back and check letter by letter, crazy what an s will do to throw a wrench in your plans when you only halfway know what you are doing lol...  Thank you again! (I voted up for you but Im not high enough on level for it to count it seems, I apologize for that...)

Comment: Done, sorry, forgot to do that yesterday...  Also, I upvoted but I am a lowly peasant and it didn't count lol...  Happy Thanksgiving!